# One of these things is not like the other... in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello Im currently constructing something that pushes a series of booleans to an array.

In the end the array will look something like this:

```
var booleanArray = [true, true, true, false, true];
```

What I want to do is create a function that will assess all the values of that boolean filled array and if there is one or more values that is false, it does something.

Is this at all possible without creating several nested if statements?

Bonus points if it stops looping through the array when it finds the first false.

Comment: Does that mean you want a different behaviour if only 1 item is different? Or 1 or more?

Comment: To be specific, what happens if two of them things are not like the other?

Comment: Do you actually *need* the array? You could just have two variables -- `wasAnythingFalse` and `wasAnythingTrue` -- and instead of pushing a boolean into the array, you just set the appropriate variable. At the end, if both are set, then you know the conditions didn't all come out the same.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli 1 or more but only when false, and cant check against homogenous instances because if theyre all false then it has to `do something` still.

Comment: @slebetman if one or more things is false

Comment: @JoeWhite Thats actually an interesting approach. So im guessing you could do an if statement that pushes to var anyFalse with `++` if there are false booleans and then at the end of the looping `if` it could check `if(anyFalse != 0){do something}`. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Can't you just loop over the array and check if each item is different to the first?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli no because if the first value is false, it will flag if a True appears, and I dont want to to do that, I only want to flag if a false appears.

Comment: You should update your question then, because it's pretty vague as it stands.

Comment: @JSArrakis: I still don't quite understand. If one or more things are different then it should return false? If all the same it should also return false? Only if one is different should it return true? Is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check for the first index of *true* and *false*:

```
// Returns true of all members are true or all are false,
// otherwise returns false
function checkBoolArray(arr) {
  return arr.indexOf(true) == -1 || arr.indexOf(false) == -1;
}
```

So if there are no *true* members they must all be false (or the array is empty), or if there are no *false* members they must all be true (or the array is empty), otherwise it returns false as there must be both *true* and *false*.

This will also return true where there are no members (i.e. the array is empty).

Answer (score 0):

the code will detect and `do something` even if one value on array is diff from the rest

```
var val = a[0];
for(i = 1; i< a.length; i++){
  if(a[i] !== val){/*do something*/}
  else{val = a[i];}
}
```

`a` being your array.
consider the code as just an idea..
you will have to check the `length` of `a`. before doing `a[0]`

Comment: To allow for any length array, just start *i* at 0. If the array has zero or 1 member, it doesn't have any that are different to others. ;-)

Comment: Eyeballing this, I believe this will fail if a[0] is the thing that is different. You have to check at least 3 things before you know what the oddball is.

Comment: @MikeBell—it checks the first value against all the others, so if the first is the one that is different, it will fail at the first check.